# Automation SQL or Filter Activities with MCC Synchronized Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, automationstudio

Sales cloud and Marketing cloud are integrated using MCC. Entities have been setup under Data Sources and sendable Data Extensions are populated. In addition, the Salesforce entities are in an attribute set associated.

When attempting to create a filter definition in Email Studio or a SQL activity in automation studio, the Salesforce Data Extensions are not available through the UX to drag and drop. In the SQL activity, I can write SQL that accesses the tables though.

I need to have these DEs available for drag and drop so business users can create data filters to populate sendable DEs to be used in journeys. What am I missing? Why are the synchronized DEs not available to drag and drop in either filter definitions or SQL activities? What is different about these vs sendable DEs I create myself which seem to have no problem showing up in the drag and drop interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still filter these data extensions by navigating to their path in the Synchronized Data Extensions folder and clicking the "Filter" icon.

That being said, SF does not recommend that you use this approach since filtering these data extensions can lead to unexpected errors which may impact your system processes. I would imagine that these data extensions aren't present in the SQL Activity UI for a somewhat similar reason (keep in mind that all of these sources are attached to the contact model with a particular configuration, which differs from your standard DE).

If you want to expose these in a simple menu that business users can navigate, then I'm afraid you are going to need to build your own application or cloudpage to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If filters are not used to move data from a synchronized data extension to a data extension that can be used in a journey, what is the correct way to allow for my users to use the sales cloud synchronized data in a journey? Data extension entry does not have access to the synchronized sources either.

Comment: Additionally, if I try to use a Data Extension Entry source for a journey, the wizard does not recognize the data extensions created from sales cloud synchronized data extensions. If I use an event Entry source using Contract Data, the data extensions are available. What am I missing?

Comment: The ideal way is to just use a Salesforce Entry Event in order to trigger off the journey and then you can use the Synchronized Data Extensions (linked to the contact model) to make any up-to-date decisions within the Journey.

If you do want to use a data extension entry event, then you can just set up an automation to query the Synchronized Data Extensions and then use the target DE as your entry event. Then you can still use Synchronized Data Extension Contact Data within the journey to check for any updates to user data on the SF side.

Comment: Awesome. Salesforce Entry Event is not an Entry Source option in my journey builder. I am looking into it now.

Comment: Best of luck to you! If you end up finding that my answer was helpful, can you mark as solved? Thank you!

Comment: @DanDoyle if you haven't solved it, yet: you have to contact support to enable salesforce events and activities in journey builder if they are not present. This can happen occasionally

Comment: I opened a case with salesforce support and they enabled as Stephan said. This was exactly the path I found I had to take. I wish it was documented that support needs to enable this. Thaks to both Jason and Stephan for the  help.

Comment: @JasonHanshaw Quick question on salesforce data event source - can this be used for a set audience, run-once batch? This event source seems active like dropping in new contacts on create or on update. For our particular use case, we have a set of accounts identifying the contacts to drop into a single journey. Is this a use case when the SQL Activity is used to build a DE for this single communication?

Comment: This is used to identify records on the SF side that meet a certain set of conditions that you specify in the entry event, so records will continue to be ingested into the journey as they meet this criteria.

If you are just generating an audience for a run-once, why don't you just use an automation rather than a journey?

Comment: Let me ask this in a question so you get credit. I am interested in understanding when to use automation and when to use journey. We have an application generating events using the Event API. This makes sense to me. Working with Sales Cloud audiences is not quite sinking in. It seems that the Salesforce Data Event entry source is equivalent to the Event API entry source. I am not understanding the standard process for handling batch communication to a set audience generated from Salesforce contacts.

Comment: If you have an action in SF that needs to trigger a series of communications immediately (i.e. account gets converted, lead is created), then a SF Entry Event in JB is definitely the only way to get this in real-time. If you have a lengthy set of communications that can branch into different flows/emails depending on user data or interactions, but the initial audience will be generated on the MC side, then you should use a DE Entry Event for JB. If you have a set audience, or one that you want to regenerate at interval, and you have a static series of deliveries/simple steps, then you use AS.

Comment: If you aren't looking to constantly inject contacts into the series of emails you are planning for this, and you have your data sources synced from SC to MC, then there really is no reason not to use automation studio. Step 1 will generate your audience, and then you can send emails or even update SC data/contacts with script activities.